# Pattern for supporting similar libraries

Tags: design-patterns

Our current framework software provides the logging mechanism using a third party library for logging the debug messages and the framework has a wrapper for it. We are also planning to use another third party debug logger library for another client. So we need to support both the logging mechanisms in the framework and the clients may choose any of the logging mechanism. What design pattern would be more appropriate in this scenario?  Reference to any existing sample code would be great.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **Adapter pattern** & also **Factory method pattern** for that.

> The Adapter pattern enables a system to use classes whose interfaces
>   don't quite match its requirements.

See information about adapter pattern with example code at the below Urls:

**C# link:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596527730-01-04.aspx

**Java link:** http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/adapter_pattern.htm

**ITarget:** The interface that the Client wants to use --> This should be a interface exposing all the methods/properties you want to use regardless of which library you use.

**Adaptee:** An implementation that needs adapting --> This will be your old and new third party debug logger libraries.

**Adapter:** The class that implements the ITarget interface in terms of the Adaptee --> This is the Adapter that implements the ITarget interface and calls Adaptee methods/properties internally. You will have separate adapters for the new and old debug logger libraries.

**Request:** An operation that the Client wants --> This will be your methods like `LogDebugInfo()`

**SpecificRequest:** The implementation of Request's functionality in the Adaptee --> This will be the actual implementation of the say `LogDebugInfo()` in the Adaptee.

> The factory method pattern is an object-oriented creational design pattern to implement the concept of factories and deals
>   with the problem of creating objects (products) without specifying the
>   exact class of object that will be created.

**Factory Method pattern:** http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570183/Factory-Method-Pattern